# How important is the correlation coefficient's variance in linear regression?

Tags: r, regression, correlation

R doesn't return the correlation coefficient's variance (or standard error) when coding `summary(linmod)`, `linmod` being a linear model with one stochastic variable. Wouldn't it be reasonable to first check this variance when reflecting on how reliable `linmod` is in terms of correlation, even before dealing with, say, the standard error of the slope which is returned by the `summary` code?

Comment: Why would you want that? What would it tell you that isn't in the summary of linmod?

Comment: I think this should be left open; it's pretty clear what the person is *asking*; it's not clear *why* he or she wants to know.

Comment: It would allow me to t-test whether r might be 0.

Comment: So would `cor.test()`, and the $t$-test of the slope coefficient (same test regardless of whether the variables are standardized).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't see what you'd stand to gain by checking the variance of the correlation before the standard error $(SE)$ of the slope. The unstandardized slope estimate's $SE$ just preserves the original scale of the predictor and response variables; it's otherwise equivalent to the $SE$ of the correlation estimate.

You can get the $SE$ of the correlation by standardizing both variables in your linear model (`summary(lm(scale(y)~scale(x)))`). E.g., with `set.seed(1);x=rnorm(9);y=rnorm(9)`, $SE_{\beta_1}=.36$. Compare to `sqrt((1-cor(x,y)^2)/(length(x)-2))`.
For another way of getting this from `cor.test()`, check out [How to compute P-value and standard error from correlation analysis of R's cor()](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16097453/2829605) on Stack Overflow.